# How to define co-ordinates for X-Y axis in JFreeChart

Tags: jfreechart

I m a newbie to JfreeChart, all I want to do is create a straight line on XY axis with co-ordinates as (x,y) = (0,0) and (6,0) 
but the default co-ordinate values for X and Y axis starts from -0.75 and 0.00 respectively.
I just want to make sure that it starts from (0,0) every time. I know its doable but i cant figure out how. Any help Appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Without your code it's hard to tell exactly how you need to do this, but you need to set the **bounds** of the **range** (X) and **domain** (Y) axis. Something like this should do:

```
plot.getRangeAxis().setLowerBound(0);
plot.getDomainAxis().setLowerBound(0);
```

where `plot` is a subclass of Plot which has a range and domain axis (that is, Plot itself does not, but XYPlot or CategoryPlot for example does, so you may need a cast).

Comment: `XYPlot plot = new XYPlot();
plot.getRangeAxis().setLowerBound(0);
plot.getDomainAxis().setLowerBound(0);
series.add(1,6);
series.add(3,6);`

this is my code. when i add `plot.getRangeAxis().setLowerBound(0);` It gives me NullPointerException.